# Why the javascript package of bootstrap does't work?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap in my website, and I have import all the "bootstrap.min.css" "bootstrap.js" and "jquery.js" file into my html file. however code following doesn't work! Anyone can help me out?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```

Comment: Please be more specific about "doesn't work". What i the error? What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5bq8U/

HTML:

```
<div align="center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('button').tooltip();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in,
>   meaning you must initialize them yourself.

Hence the answer of `$('button[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` called on page load or `$(document).ready()` should target only the buttons which have the tool-tip markup.